# Custom Upload Progress Bar React

Tags: reactjs, api, request, progress-bar

I am working on a web application where i sending data to the server and getting the response back. Here's the workflow :

User uploads a video and it get sends to the server and get the response back. In the meantime i want to show a custom progress.

So far I'm showing a progress bar by using Progress Event in JavaScript like this.

```
const options = {
  onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
    const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;
    let percent = Math.floor((loaded * 100) / total);

    if (percent < 100) {
      this.setState({ uploadPercentage: percent });
    }
  },
};
```

And I am sending this alongwith the data to the server

```
      axios.post(URL, data, options)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          this.setState(
            {
              uploadPercentage: 100,
              data: data,
            },
            () => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({ uploadPercentage: 0 });
              }, 1000);
            }
          );
        })
        .then((error) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
```

And this is how I am rendering progress bar

```
{
  this.state.uploadPercentage > 0 && (
    <div className="progress mb-2">
      <div
        className="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated"
        role="progressbar"
        aria-valuenow={`${this.state.uploadPercentage}%`}
        aria-valuemin="0"
        aria-valuemax="100"
        style={{ width: `${this.state.uploadPercentage}%` }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But i want to show some text sequence like this each should be shown for few seconds

Initializing Model....
Disintegrating video into frames.....
Finding Faces.....
Segregating into mask or no mask.....

and then the output will show up.

Can anyone help me out?